# how to display map on vf page in salesforce

Tags: apex, visualforce, community, visualforce-component

how to create a map that contains the account and list of corresponding contacts then we have to display this map on a VF page.

Answer (score 5):

So you can create a map. this map can contain Account and there related contact records.

Like

```
map<Account, List<Contact>> mapAccountToContacts = new map<Account, List<Contact>>();
```

SO basically if you are using this map in your vf page then this variable should be in get set property

```
public class myClaass{
public map<Account, List<Contact>> mapAccountToContacts {get;set;}

  public myClaass(){
    mapAccountToContacts = map<Account, List<Contact>>();
    // query here and add into this map
  }
}
```

If you just wanted to display these records then use `private set` This is reduce view state and you can't update records from page.

And add the values in map. You can use subquery to get the contacts related to each Account record.

And then you can assign to map.

```
for(Account objAcc :[SELECT Name, (SELECT FirstName, LastName FROM Contacts) FROM Account])
{
    mapAccountToContacts.put(objAcc, objAcc.Contacts);
}
```

In VF page. You need 2 `apex:repeat`. One `apex:repeat` to iterate over map and another `apex:repeat` to iterate over list contacts that are associated with each Account record.

```
<apex:repeat value="{!mapAccountToContacts}" var="mapAccKey">
    Account Name: {!mapAccKey.Name}

    <apex:repeat value="{!mapAccountToContacts[mapAccKey]}" var="con">
    Contacts First Name :{!con.LastName}
    Contacts Last Name  :{!con.LastName} 
    </apex:repeat>
</apex:repeat>
```

Comment: it is showing error create apex property classname.mapAccountToContacts

Comment: it is showing nothing in vf page

Comment: VF page-

<apex:page controller="MapOnVf">

<apex:repeat value="{!Mmap}" var="a">
    Account Name:{!a.name}
    
<apex:repeat value="{!Mmap[a]}" var="c">
    Contact Last Name:{!c.lastName}
    
    
    </apex:repeat>
</apex:repeat>

  
</apex:page>

Comment: @lee have you queried Account  and added all the values in map ..??????

Comment: VF- PAGE:

<apex:page controller="MapOnVf">

<apex:repeat value="{!Mmap}" var="a">
    Account Name:{!a.name}
    
<apex:repeat value="{!Mmap[a]}" var="c">
    Contact Last Name:{!c.lastName}
    
    
    </apex:repeat>
</apex:repeat>

  
</apex:page>


controller:-

public class MapOnVf {

    
    public Map<account,List<contact>> Mmap {get;set;}
     
    public void getMapOnvf(){ 
     
     for(Account acc :[SELECT Name, (SELECT FirstName, LastName FROM Contacts) FROM Account])
        {
            Mmap.put(acc, acc.Contacts);
        }
     
     }
    
}

but it is showing nothing

Comment: i have used it but it is showing bkank page

Comment: @lee Can you put debug and check you are getting records in debug log or not.. your query returning values of not ?

Comment: it is working but without proper lining and adjustment

Comment: @lee I think you can handle this  your own since this is related to designing.. You can do what ever you want..

Comment: @lee any problem. Are you trying to remove my code/explanation from my ans ?