# Visualforce: apex:repeat and Map

Tags: apex, visualforce, map

In my controller I have a map of integers and strings which I want to display as checkboxes.

The controller:

```
public Map<Integer, String> xmlCatalogsMap {get;set;}
public Set<Integer> xmlCatalogsKeys {get;set;}

public void getXMLCatalogs() {
    String sql = 'SELECT BOID__c, Name FROM ZXMLCatalogs__c ORDER BY Name';
    List<ZXMLCatalogs__c> result = Database.query(sql);
    Map<Integer, String> xmlCatalogsMap = new Map<Integer, String>();

    for (ZXMLCatalogs__c c : result) {
        xmlCatalogsMap.put(Integer.valueOf(c.BOID__c), c.Name);
    }

    Set<Integer> xmlCatalogsKeys = xmlCatalogsMap.keySet();
}
```

`getXMLCatalogs()` is called from constructor.

Now I want to display a checkbox for each integer/string pair. Integer/key should be the checkbox value and the string should be the label:

```
<apex:repeat value="{!xmlCatalogsKeys}" var="i">
    <apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
        <apex:inputCheckbox label="{!xmlCatalogsMap[i]}" value="{!i}" html-name="CatalogId" />
    </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
</apex:repeat>
```

I read 
[how to display map on vf page in salesforce](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/113527/how-to-display-map-on-vf-page-in-salesforce)
and
[How to reference a map's keySet() and individual map elements within Visualforce? Get 'Unknown function' error](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/34582/how-to-reference-a-maps-keyset-and-individual-map-elements-within-visualforce)

When I compile with Sublime/Maven I always get the below error without line number:

> Unknown property 'i'

Why can't I use `i` (or any other variable name) as a variable?

Comment: one error I can see `Set<Integer> xmlCatalogsKeys = xmlCatalogsMap.keySet();` you should reinitialise the variable here. You have assign the values `xmlCatalogsKeys = xmlCatalogsMap.keySet();`

Comment: Could you test with `Set<Integer> xmlCatalogsKeys = new Set<Integer>(xmlCatalogsMap.keySet());` ?

Comment: I changed the assignment of xmlCatalogsKeys, but the problem remains. Other examples here use keySet and a variable too.

Comment: Just tried the same conditions and it's working with other type of components. It looks like a bug with the `apex:inputCheckbox`

Comment: Please check my answer, it is working

Answer (score 3):

In the line:

```
<apex:inputCheckbox label="{!xmlCatalogsMap[i]}" value="{!i}" html-name="CatalogId" />
```

value attribute should be Boolean. So that checkbox can be marked as check or uncheck.

Currently it's Integer. That's why it is showing error.

To fix this problem, set up a map of Integer to Boolean, then bind the checkbox to that instead.

```
public Map<Integer, Boolean> xmlCatalogsChecked { get; set; }

public void getXMLCatalogs() {
    // Query omitted
    xmlCatalogsChecked = new Map<Integer, Boolean>();
    for (ZXMLCatalogs__c c : result) {
        xmlCatalogsMap.put(Integer.valueOf(c.BOID__c), c.Name);
        // Assign default state
        xmlCatalogsChecked.put(Integer.valueOf(c.BOID__c), false);
    }
}
```

---

```
<apex:inputCheckbox label="{!xmlCatalogsMap[i]}" value="{!xmlCatalogsChecked[i]}" 
    html-name="CatalogId" />
```

> **Update based on Comments**
>
> *Main issue in your code is this line at getXMLCatalogs() method which is initializes the map and makes that empty.*

```
Map<Integer, String> xmlCatalogsMap = new Map<Integer, String>();
```

I have create apex class and pages just like you and it is working correctly.

**Apex class**

```
public class DealerController
{
    public Map<Integer, String> xmlCatalogsMap {get;set;}
    public Map<Integer, Boolean> xmlCatalogsChecked { get; set; }

    public Set<Integer> xmlCatalogsKeys {get;set;}

    public DealerController()
    {
        getXMLCatalogs();
    }

    public void getXMLCatalogs() {
        xmlCatalogsKeys = new Set<Integer>();

        String sql = 'SELECT Dealer_Number__c, Name FROM Dealer__c ORDER BY Name';
        List<Dealer__c> result = Database.query(sql);

        xmlCatalogsMap = new Map<Integer, String>();
        xmlCatalogsChecked = new Map<Integer, Boolean>();

        for (Dealer__c c : result) {
            xmlCatalogsMap.put(Integer.valueOf(c.Dealer_Number__c), c.Name);
            // Assign default state
            xmlCatalogsChecked.put(Integer.valueOf(c.Dealer_Number__c), false);
        }
         xmlCatalogsKeys = new Set<Integer>(xmlCatalogsMap.keySet());


    }

}
```

**Visualforce**

```
<apex:page id="dealerPage" controller="DealerController" action="{!getXMLCatalogs}">
    <apex:form >
    <apex:pageBlock >
    <apex:pageBlockSection >
    <apex:repeat value="{!xmlCatalogsKeys}" var="i">


            <apex:inputCheckbox label="{!xmlCatalogsMap[i]}" value="{!xmlCatalogsChecked[i]}" 
            html-name="CatalogId" />


    </apex:repeat>
    </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

**Result**
[image: checkbox]

Comment: I tried the boolean map and value="{!xmlCatalogsChecked[i]}". No compile error, but checkboxes are not displayed. It's just a headache.

Comment: Please check my ans, it is working as expected.

Comment: Ok, it seems that value attribute can only store boolean. Would be better for my case to store ID numbers, so I switched to a multi selectList, much easier.

Answer (score 0):

> Why can't I use i (or any other variable name) as a variable?

I believe the issue is that what you want to do in your code is the following:

```
{!xmlCatalogsMap.get(xmlCatalogsKeys)}
```

You'd likely be better off doing that in your controller and creating a list of `xmlCatalogMapValues`.

Comment: Unfortunately the first method won't work, because we can't call methods with parameters that way in Visualforce. The second suggestion is definitely preferred unless there's a good reason for having the map in the first place.

Comment: Exactly and that was the point I was trying to make.